# Python: Change Cmd Startup folder programmatically

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd

I am trying to create a python program to easily change my cmd startup folder(rather than typing cd ... to navigate to the desired file)
But first I need to figure out how to change it without having to type regedit.exe into cmd.
After going through python documentation this is where I got:

```
from winreg import*

a=OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\\")
SetValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\\",REG_SZ,"cd\\the path that I want.")
```

This code does edit the string value (I believe that is what its called) Default.
But what I need it to do is to edit the string value Autorun
 #I tried diffrent ways of putting  Autorun in that SetValue function but it didn't work.
Note: both Default and Autorun are in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor.
I've also tried

```
SetValueEx(a,"Autorun",0,REG_SZ,"cd\\The path that I wantsss.")#Don't know if this is the right way to use it.
```

But this gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    SetValueEx(a,"Autorun",0,REG_SZ,"cd\\The path that I wantsss.")
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

I use python 3.1 and windows7
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using SetValueEx instead.  You will probably need to use the handle returned by OpenKey as the key.  (The on-line documentation says that the value_name parameter to SetValueEx is a key name, but I'm guessing that's a typo.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I tried your way access was denied.Do I need to get administrators' right how can I do that.(Note: I am the administrator).

Comment: You have to specify KEY_WRITE or KEY_ALL_ACCESS as the fourth argument to OpenKey.  The default is KEY_READ which gives you read-only access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use SetValueEx and also open the key with appropriate access rights, either KEY_WRITE or KEY_ALL_ACCESS, like this:

```
from winreg import*

a=OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\Microsoft\\Command Processor",0,KEY_WRITE)
SetValueEx(a,"Autorun",0,REG_SZ,"cd\\The path that I wantsss.")
CloseKey(a)
```